# Is it safe to call function accepting parameters by r-value reference twice with moved object?

Tags: c++

I have the following piece of code. I expected it to fail, i.e. I thought that move constructor would execute when entering 'send' function and, when trying to call 'send' again this should be an invalid operation ('a' is no longer a valid object because it was moved from). But somehow this code executes without any problem. 
Output shows that move constructor is not even executed.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {
    int *ptr;
    A() { cout << "ctor A" << endl; ptr = new int(1); }
    A(A&& o) { cout << "move ctor" << endl; ptr = o.ptr; o.ptr = nullptr; }
    ~A() { cout << "dtor" << endl; delete ptr; }
    void send() { cout << *ptr << endl; }
};

bool send(A&& a, int i)
{
    if (i == 0) { 
        cout << "returning" << endl; 
        return false; 
    }
    cout << "sending" << endl;
    a.send();
    return true;
}
int main()
{ 
    A a;
    if(!send(move(a),0))
        send(move(a),1);
}
```

Output:

```
ctor A
returning
sending
1
dtor
```

However when when I change the 'send' method to accept A objects by value, the problem appears exactly how I had imagined. Move ctor is called, and when second time 'send' is called, 'a' is not valid, we have segmentation fault.

```
bool send(A a, int i)
{
    if (i == 0) { 
        cout << "returning" << endl; 
        return false; 
    }
    cout << "sending" << endl;
    a.send();
    return true;
}
```

Result:

```
ctor A
move ctor
returning
dtor
move ctor
sending
Segmentation fault
```

So, move constructor is only called when moved object is passed by value. Ok, I got it.

**My question however is this: is it safe to declare function 'send' this way, i.e. to accept parameters by r-value reference and then call it with moved object multiple times? I know that std::move doesn't really move anything, only creates r-value reference, but anyhow: is it safe? Or, in other words, is there a guideline which says "Don't do this"?**

[https://wandbox.org/permlink/R5spfEGI7WZR9lwR][1]

Comment: use after move is undefined behavior

Comment: You are not moving anything in your first example.

Comment: I thought so. Thank you.

Comment: I know, I wrote this (move doesn't really move anything). My question was different: is it safe to have functions like this and call it with moved object twice.

Comment: @skeller Use after move depends on the guaranties the type chooses to make regarding it's moved-from state. For example, `std::shared_ptr` is empty but otherwise completely usable after a move. Any sensible type must still be destructible, and generally should at a minimum be assignable after being moved from, if that operation makes sense for that type in the first place.

Comment: Invocation of `std::move` is only required to produce an rvalue, it does not make the object "moved". If you are not really moving an object inside of this function then most likely there is no point in accepting an rvalue reference

Comment: After move the object is supposed to be in state called Destructible and Assignable (that's why shared_ptr behaviour is OK)

Comment: @YotKay `std::shared_ptr` actually provides additional guaranties, such as being empty. Most container-like objects will be in an unspecified by safe state though. As far as I know, the language doesn't require that a moved-from object be assignable or even explicitly says it has to be destructible. But it's sensible to make sure your types do offer those guarantee. If it *does* say otherwise, I would be glad to find out where.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I cannot provide a citation from the standard now, I think I saw it once in some CppCon presentation or the like.

Answer (score 0):

If you actually move the object within the send function, then you will see the behavior you expect (segmentation fault when a.send is called). For example:

```
bool send(A &&a, int i)
{
    A b = move(a);

    if (i == 0) { 
        cout << "returning" << endl; 
        return false; 
    }
    cout << "sending" << endl;
    a.send();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to write && at the parameter. But you are right here. However, if I delay the move until after the if statement, then again the code will work fine. I feel this is a bad design, dangerous, and smells undefined behaviour. What do others think?